# How to update PrefixChar in Command Service? Discord Bot c#

Tags: c#, json, discord, discord.net

```
UsingCommands(input =>
{
     input.PrefixChar = _dbContext.Prefix;
     //input.CustomPrefixHandler = message => 5; 
     input.AllowMentionPrefix = true;
}));
```

This is how it is normal set up. The prefix is pulled from the File and put into memory as the PrefixChar.

```
_commandService.CreateCommand("changeprefix").Parameter("message").Do(async e =>
            {
                char prefix;
                if (!char.TryParse(e.Args[0], out prefix))
                {
                    await e.User.SendMessage($"Please use the correct format: {_dbContext.Prefix}changeprefix ");
                }
                else
                { 
                    _dbContext.SetPrefix(prefix);
                    //_commandService.Config.CustomPrefixHandler(e.Message);
                    await e.User.SendMessage($"Prefix is now {_dbContext.Prefix}");
                }
            });
```

This is the command that is ran when a user wants to change the Prefix. The prefix is changed in the Json File but I can not seem to find a way to change the CommandService.config so that its now looking for the new prefix.

I have changed the Json file and it shows that the memory of the file is changed but the only thing not changing is the CommandService.Config PrefixChar.

I have commented out some of the ways I was trying to get it to work using the CustomPrefixHandler but I still cant seem to get to work.

Edit:

```
var client = new DiscordClient(input =>
{
    input.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
    input.LogHandler = Log;
}).UsingCommands(input =>
{
    input.PrefixChar = _dbContext.Prefix;
    input.CustomPrefixHandler = message => 5;
    input.AllowMentionPrefix = true;
});

_commandService = new CommandService();
_commandService = client.GetService<CommandService>();
```

This is how I tried to instantiate a new command service. If I use this It still only works with the original Prefix. Example:

!changeprefix #
//Then running another command

'#'help //Doesnt work

!help //Works

Comment: is it possible to create a new CommandService with the new prefix pulled from the file? just tossing out an idea since I'm not sure whether or not you can set the prefix character on an existing CommandService

Comment: I tried that by doing making a new client and setting the commandService. Made edits to my question

Comment: @PeterG See edits